# Leaving a cell blank in Excel until the data is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need help with an Excel formula. I am trying to create an MPG tracker for my company vehicles, and I would like the results of a formula to remain blank until all the relevant data has been entered. I have my starting mileage in cell B9, my ending mileage in cell C9, and my total miles in cell D9. I would like the total miles cell (D9) to remain blank until I have entered my ending mileage at the end of the day. The current Formula I have entered in cell D9 now is: `=C9-B9`. See the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `IF`, `OR` and `ISBLANK` like this:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B9),ISBLANK(C9)), "", C9-B9)
```

Comment: Bingo!!  That did the trick.  I really need to take an advanced excel class to get a better understanding of what all the functions actually mean.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user302068 `ISBLANK()` returns true or false if the cell is blank. `OR` will return either true or false: if all inside brackets is false, it will return false. If only one returns true, it returns true. I hope that makes things a little clearer :) `IF` should be easy to understand `IF(expr, res1, res2)` : if the expression `expr` is true, then calculate `res1`, else calculate `res2`.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I had to delete the "DAY" and just enter the value, so =IF(OR(ISBLANK(E2)),"",E2+6) Now subsequent rows only add + 6 from column E.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a conditional formula using the `IF` function. Microsoft has a whole [article](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-conditional-formulas-ca916c57-abd8-4b44-997c-c309b7307831?CorrelationId=ad066f7d-6a6e-47c3-b939-7e5617268e75&ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU) about how they work. Your solution would look like this:

```
=IF((C9-B9)<=0, "", C9-B9)
```

Comment: @CanadianLuke I corrected that piece to be `<=` instead of just `<`. The way it is now, it's faster and simpler than the other answer.