# An Excel 2010 Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Currently I am working on a formula for Excel 2010. The formula works good, but I need to keep it from displaying results until I have actually input the data in the columns. The Formula I am working with is,

```
=IF(AND(OR(A3="Info",A3="Different INFO"),F3="Yes"),"Released/Reset","No Release or Reset")
```

I have tried using `ISBLANK` in the statement but it returns an error that I am using too many arguments, or returns the `#VALUE!` Error.
I need some guidance.

Comment: Maybe related http://superuser.com/q/719850/666773

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your original formula in another `IF` statement that determines whether either of the two relevant cells is blank:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A3), ISBLANK(F3)), "", IF(AND(OR(A3 = "Info", A3 = "Different INFO"), F3 = "Yes"), "Released/Reset", "No Release or Reset"))
```

Comment: While your formula might be correct, please also explain what was necessary to fix in the original one.