# Leaving a cell blank in excel until the data is entered, but if it is = or < then zero I want zero to be entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

The info on "[Leaving a cell blank in excel until the data is entered](https://superuser.com/questions/719850/leaving-a-cell-blank-in-excel-until-the-data-is-entered)" worked great, but it gives me a negative number. I would really like for it to
give me a zero if it is = or < than zero. Below is the formula I have 
so far. I'm stuck at getting it to enter zero for = or < than zero.
How do I get it to enter a zero?

```
  D11       E11             G11
01/29/2016  01/18/2016      =IF(OR(ISBLANK(D11),ISBLANK(E11))," ",E11-D11)
```

Comment: Not sure I'm tracking this properly. Try: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D11),ISBLANK(E11)),"",MAX(E11-D11,0))`

Answer (score 0):

You needed one more IF at the end to check if it's Greater that Zero

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(D11),ISBLANK(E11))," ",IF(E11-D11=<0,0,E11-D11))
```